# Two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the character from the list generated from the second string.
At the end, if the array is empty it is the permutation of two strings else not.

Is this logic fine?

```
def is_permutation(string1, string2):
    if len(string1) != len(string2):
        return False
    string2 = list(string2)
    for char in string1:
        if char in string2:
            string2.remove(char)
    if not string2:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(is_permutation("abc", "cba"))
    print(is_permutation("bc", "ab"))
    print(is_permutation("dog", "god"))
```

Comment: Logic is fine but not performances, try to use a Counter object.

Comment: Have a look at [Determining if a word is an anagram of another](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96475/determining-if-a-word-is-an-anagram-of-another) for more efficient approaches.

Comment: Thanks, I have been told not to use any library.

Comment: A Counter is a special case of a dictionary where the key is the character and the value is the number of time it occurs. You could implement it without any libraries.

Comment: Ok, what would be time complexity for it. For my approach, it is O(n).